# Finding the equation of tangent of a hyperbola

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $(x_{0}, y_{0})$, where $y_{0} ≠ 0$, be a point on the hyperbola $\frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1$.

I've found the gradient of the tangent line passing through the hyperbola at $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ to be: 
$$ \frac {x_{0}b^2}{y_{0}a^2} $$

Subsequently, i tried to form the equation of the tangent using the following formula: 
$$ (y-y_{0}) = \frac {x_{0}b^2}{y_{0}a^2} (x-x_{0}) $$

However, i've completely no clue on how i should factorise the above equation to attain the answer as follow: 
$$ \frac {x_{0}x}{a^2} - \frac {y_{0}y}{b^2} = 1 $$

Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214977/general-equation-of-a-tangent-line-to-a-hyperbola?rq=1

Comment: the equation of a hyperbola is given by $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Comment: $\frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} = 1$ is an ellipse ?

Comment: $$ (y-y_{0}) = \frac {x_{0}b^2}{y_{0}a^2} (x-x_{0}) \implies \frac{(y-y_0)y_0}{b^2} = \frac{(x-x_0)x_0}{a^2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On rearrangement $$\dfrac{xx_0}{a^2}-\dfrac{yy_0}{b^2}=\dfrac{x_0^2}{a^2}-\dfrac{y_0^2}{b^2}$$

But $(x_0,y_0)$ lies on the hyperbola

Comment: how did you do the rearrangement? I can't seem to get the above.

Comment: @idolo, Take $x,y$ in one side and $x_0^2,y_0^2$ in the other

Comment: oh yes, i got it thanks. However, how does $\frac {x_{0}^2}{a^2} - \frac {y_{0}^2}{b^2} = 1$ as per the answer shown in the question?

Comment: @idolo, As $$(x_0,y_0)$$ lies on the hyperbola