# Find an equation of the tangent line to the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ that passes through the point (1,2)

Tags: calculus

My friends are discusing this question but They don't agree with my answer, and They don't know how to solve.

My answer was

$y = x+3/2$

Comment: the curve in your title is a circle

Comment: @WillJagy sorry, already fixed it

Comment: Well an obvious difficulty with your answer is that it does not pass through $(1,2)$...

Comment: sorry again, I fixed the equation again

Comment: hjx, draw a careful picture. The edit you made 40 seconds ago gives a question with an answer... Not the answer you wrote, of course

Comment: @WillJagy now it is right, sorry

Comment: Your equation is still not satisfied by $(1,2)$. It would seem that your friends are right to disagree with your solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [general equation of a tangent line to a hyperbola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214977/general-equation-of-a-tangent-line-to-a-hyperbola)

Comment: As a simple drawing shows, there should be four answers to this question (i.e. four different tangents). One of them is the the vertical line $x=1$, which is tangent to the hyperbola at $(1,0)$ and passes by the given point $(1,2)$.

Comment: @AndersBeta I disagree. I think there will be 2 tangents (try making a crude graph)

Comment: It is not possible to find a real equation of the tangent line to the hyperbola  x^2−y^2=1  that passes through the point (1,2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a tangent line, you would have to take a derivative. Implicitly.
$$x^2-y^2=1$$
$$2x-2yy'=0$$
$$y'=\frac{x}y=\frac{x}{\pm\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$
We use point-slope form to find the equation of a tangent line. For our purposes the point of tangency will be $(a, \pm\sqrt{a^2-1})$. The plus will be for the top, and the minus for the bottom point of tangency. (Because the positive square root represents the top half of the graph after solving for y, and vice versa for the bottom)
$$y-\sqrt{a^2-1}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}(x-a)$$
This equation satisfies the point $(1,2)$.
$$2-\sqrt{a^2-1}=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}(1-a)$$
`Multiply`
$$2\sqrt{a^2-1}-(a^2-1)=a-a^2$$
`Rearrange`
$$a-1=2\sqrt{a^2-1}$$
`Square both sides (This cancels out the plus-or-minus effect!)`
$$a^2-2a+1=4a^2-4$$
$$3a^2+2a-5=0$$
$$(3x+5)(x-1)=0$$
Our final two points of tangency are $a=-\frac53$ and $a=1$.
Our tangent lines must be:
$$y-0=\frac10(x-1)\ \rightarrow\ x=1$$
$$y-(-\frac43)=\frac{\frac53}{\frac43}(x-(-\frac53))\ \rightarrow\ y=\frac54x+\frac34$$
Edit [Mohammad Riazi-Kermani]: Note that the lines pass through the point $(1,2)$.
`The top point uses the positive y-coordinates. Also, a slope of infinity...`
`The bottom point uses the negative y-coordinates.`

Comment: Yes, the line $x=1$ is an obvious solution. Now you can see the other tangent line, and how to get it. Hope this helps! At least, I had fun solving it...

Comment: everything is easy after it gets done, the hardness is doing for the first time. As a teacher of mine used to say, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The line x=1 is an obvious solution.

For other solutions, find the slope of tangent in two ways and make them equal to find the equation.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^2}{1^1}-\frac{y^2}{1^2}=1$$

Suppose the slope of the tangent is $m^{1}$, then the tangent passes through $P(1,2)$

Equation of tangent is $$y-2=m(x-1)=mx-m$$
$$y=mx+(2-m)$$

Condition for tangency is $c^2=a^2m^2-b^2$
$$(2-m)^2=m^2-1$$
$$4+m^2-4m=m^2-1$$
$$4m=5$$
$$m=\frac54$$
Substituting $m=\frac54$ in $y-2=mx-m$ we get,
$$y=\frac54x+\frac34$$

Comment: This is not a complete solution, since it misses the vertical line $x=1$.